# warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Getting the error in the title based on the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
// import { browserHistory, hashHistory, Router } from 'react-router'
// import createMemoryHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory'
import { browserHistory, hashHistory, Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Portfolio from './portfolio/Portfolio'
import Home from './home/Home'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'

// const history = createMemoryHistory(location);
// console.log('history', history);

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ Home }/>
            <Route exact={ true } path="/portfolio" component={ Portfolio }/>
            <Route component={ NoMatch } />
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Routes
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @Chris `^4.1.1` I'm using react-router-dom

Comment: Did you upgrade to version 4 recently? It seems like you have a mix of pre-v4 and post-v4 syntax.

Comment: Been on 4 since starting this project, the comments are solutions I've tried, but I guess are older deprecated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace Router with BrowserRouter and use Switch as from react-router-dom version4.0, Router can not have more than one child.

```
import { browserHistory, hashHistory, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and replace routes with below code:

```
const Routes = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
             <Switch>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ Home }/>
                <Route exact={ true } path="/portfolio" 
                       component={ Portfolio }/>
                <Route component={ NoMatch } />
             </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```